# Twilio node library: "Client requires an Account SID and Auth Token"

Tags: twilio

This seems like a very simple and straightforward question, but I can't seem to get past an error in the node twilio setup API, and I feel out of ideas because there isn't too many places I can find problems.

I receive the following error when setting up twilio:

```
Client requires an Account SID and Auth Token set explicitly or via the TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID and TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN environment variables
```

My code:

```
  var accountSid = 'SID';
  var authToken = 'Auth Token';
  var client = require('twilio')(accountSid)(authToken);

  client.messages.create({
    to: '+1xxxxxxx',
    from: '+1xxxxxxx',
    body: 'Hey, just wanted to remind you about something'
  }, function (err, response) {
    console.log('response from twilio is ', response);
  });
```

I've also tried putting the strings in directly instead of using variables, and receive the same error. Am I really missing something here? It seems like this should work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Change this:

```
var client = require('twilio')(accountSid)(authToken);
```

to this:

```
var client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);
```

Comment: not working in my case